# I am trying to connect mysql database with node.js with help of sequelize but I it is showing access denied

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to connect mysql database with sequelize did all require stuffs like granting privileges etc.
but then also I am getting error

> "node:21352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
> SequelizeAccessDeniedError: Access denied for user ''@'localhost'
> (using password: YES)
> at ConnectionManager.connect (e:\HTML CSS JSS\Node\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:118:17)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
> at async ConnectionManager._connect (e:\HTML CSS JSS\Node\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:318:24)
> at async e:\HTML CSS JSS\Node\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:250:32
> at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (e:\HTML CSS JSS\Node\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:280:7)
> at async e:\HTML CSS JSS\Node\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:613:26
> at async Sequelize.authenticate (e:\HTML CSS JSS\Node\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:867:5) (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) (node:21352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
> not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled
> promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict`
> (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1) (node:21352) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code. "

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration because it seems that the user is not detected, maybe the password too